# Metric on a riemannian manifold with for a constant positive curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Is it true the following statement?

> Let $(M,g)$ be a 2-dimensional riemannian manifold with constant
>   positive curvature (equal to 1). For all $p\in M$ there exists a local coordinate
>   system $(\theta,\phi)$  such that $g=d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta d\phi^2$.

Where can I find proof of this?

Comment: The sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ has curvature $K=1$.

Comment: Which textbook are you reading? Do you know Cartan's theorem that curvature determines the metric?